# Haskell Program Low Performance Compared with Perl

Tags: performance, perl, haskell

I am doing a Facebook Hackercup 2015 problem with Haskell and got stuck on [this problem](http://codeforces.com/gym/100579/attachments).

Input: Begins with an integer T, the number of questions. For each question, there is one line containing 3 space-separated integers:A, B, and K.

Output: For the ith question, print a line containing "Case #i: " followed by the number of integers in the inclusive range [A, B] with a primacity of K.

Primacity of a number X is the number of its prime factors. For example, the primacity of 12 is 2 (as it's divisible by primes 2 and 3), the primacity of 550 is 3 (as it's divisible by primes 2, 5, and 11), and the primacity of 7 is 1 (as the only prime it's divisible by is 7).

1 ≤ T ≤ 100 
2 ≤ A ≤ B ≤ 10^7 
1 ≤ K ≤ 10^9

Here is my Haskell solution:

```
import System.IO
import Data.List
import Control.Monad

incEvery :: Int -> [(Int -> Int)]
incEvery n = (cycle ((replicate (n-1) id) ++ [(+ 1)]))

primes2 :: [Int]
primes2 = sieve 2 (replicate (10^7) 0)
  where
    sieve _ [] = []
    sieve n (a:xs) = (a + (if a == 0 then 1 else 0))
      : if a == 0 then
          sieve (n+1) (zipWith ($) (incEvery n) xs)
        else
          sieve (n+1) xs

process :: (Int, Int, Int) -> Int
process (lo, hi, k) =
  length . filter (\(a, b) -> a >= lo && a <= hi && b == k) . zip [2,3..] $ primes2

readIn :: [String] -> (Int, Int, Int)
readIn =
  (\[x, y, z] -> (x, y, z)) . fmap (read::String->Int) . take 3

lib :: String -> String
lib xs = unlines . fmap (\(i, x) -> "Case #" ++ (show i) ++ ": " ++ x) . zip [1,2..]
  . fmap parse . tail . lines $ xs
  where
    parse = (show . process . readIn . words)

main :: IO ()
main = interact lib
```

Here is my Perl solution:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $max = 10000010;

my @f = (0) x $max;

for my $i (2 .. $max) {
    if($f[$i] == 0) {
        $f[$i] = 1;
        # print $i . "\n";
        for my $j (2 .. ($max / $i)) {
            $f[$i * $j] ++;
        }
    }
}

my $k =  <STDIN>;
for my $i (1 .. $k) {
    my $line = <STDIN>;
    if($line) {
        chomp $line;
        my ($a, $b, $t) = split(' ', $line);
        my $ans = 0;
        for my $j ($a .. $b) {
            if($f[$j] == $t) {
                $ans ++;
            }
        }
        print "Case #$i: " . $ans . "\n";
    }    
}
```

Though I am using the same sieving algorithm for both languages, the Haskell version is significantly slower than Perl version on 10^7 scale of data.
Basically the following Haskell function is slower than its Perl counterpart:

```
incEvery :: Int -> [(Int -> Int)]
incEvery n = (cycle ((replicate (n-1) id) ++ [(+ 1)]))

primes2 :: [Int]
primes2 = sieve 2 (replicate (10^7) 0)
  where
   sieve _ [] = []
   sieve n (a:xs) = (a + (if a == 0 then 1 else 0))
   : if a == 0 then
      sieve (n+1) (zipWith ($) (incEvery n) xs)
     else
      sieve (n+1) xs
```

I think both recursion and `(zipWith ($) (incEvery n) xs)` are causing the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: did you compile the program or invoke it in ghci, did you compile with optimizations; read is known to be slow, as well as using `String`, try switching to `Text` !

Comment: I tried both and both of them are slower than Perl. My ghc version is 7.10.3. I don't think it is read's problem because obviously IO is not the bottleneck here.

Comment: Could you post the problem statement here, so we don't have to go digging for it?

Comment: Sure I have done that.

Answer (score 8):

There is absolutely no reason why you need to resort to imperative programming to gain performance. The unique thing about Haskell is you have to learn to think differently if you want to program in a purely functional manner. Exploit laziness to speed things up a bit:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Control.Applicative ( pure, (<$>) )
import Data.List           ( nub )
import Data.Monoid         ( (<>) )

isPrime :: (Integral i) => i -> Bool
isPrime n = isPrime_ n primes
  where isPrime_ n (p:ps)
          | p * p > n      = True
          | n `mod` p == 0 = False
          | otherwise      = isPrime_ n ps

primes :: (Integral i) => [i]
primes = 2 : filter isPrime [3,5..]

primeFactors :: (Integral i) => i -> [i]
primeFactors n = factors n primes
  where factors n (x:xs)
          | x * x > n      = [n]
          | n `mod` x == 0 = x : factors (n `div` x) (x:xs)
          | otherwise      = factors n xs

primacity :: (Integral i) => i -> Int
primacity = length . nub . primeFactors

user :: IO Int
user = do
  xs <- getLine
  let a :: Int = read . takeWhile (/=' ') . dropN 0 $ xs
  let b :: Int = read . takeWhile (/=' ') . dropN 1 $ xs
  let k :: Int = read . takeWhile (/=' ') . dropN 2 $ xs
  let n = length . filter (== k) . fmap primacity $ [a..b]
  pure n
    where
      dropN 0 = id
      dropN n = dropN (pred n) . drop 1 . dropWhile (/= ' ')

printNTimes :: Int -> Int -> IO ()
printNTimes 0 _ = pure ()
printNTimes n total = do
  ans <- user
  putStr $ "Case #" <> show (total - n + 1) <> ": "
  putStrLn $ show ans
  printNTimes (pred n) total

main :: IO ()
main = do
  n :: Int <- read <$> getLine
  printNTimes n n
```

This is basically mutual recursion mixed with laziness. Might take a while to understand it, but I can guarantee that it's fast.

Comment: FInally someone who shows the pure solution. I *really* couldn't see how vectors would be of any use here! As if the primacity of every number was not fixed from the beginning of time! And it is not subject to change anytime soon :)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, of course. You're effectively using two different algorithms. Your Haskell `zipWith ($) (incEvery n) xs` has to process *every* entry of your list, while your Perl `for my $j (2 .. ($max / $i)) { $f[$i * $j] ++; }` only has to process the entries it actually increments, which is a factor of `$i` faster. This is a prototypical example of a problem where mutable arrays are helpful: in Haskell you can use `STUArray`, for example.

Comment: Arrays are probably fastest, but the O'Neill sieve is arguably the best match to Haskell. The version in the `NumberSieves` package is much faster than the one in the paper, but it could certainly be improved by using a better priority queue (specializing to `Word64`, to begin with).

Comment: "This is a prototypical example of a problem where mutable arrays are helpful" - really? Would it be easier to re-write all the code to work with mutable arrays, or any other mutable data structure, than simply changing the one part of the algorithm that is "bad". Instead of increment the list directly, store a `Map [Int] Int` of which factors must increment which digit - the total size of this map is always less than 10 so insert/delete is essentially constant time. There is a version of this [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Prime_numbers) (3.11).